# How can I find the subgroups of $D_5$

Tags: group-theory

So I've found all the cyclic subgroups:
$\langle e\rangle$, $\langle r\rangle$, $\langle sr^n\rangle$, and $D_5$ itself (which are 8 subgroups), but how do I know if these are all? How can I find the rest?

Comment: Hint: What are the possible orders of the subgroups?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I haven't learnt about Lagrange's theorem yet, so I think I'm supposed to do without it.

Comment: Then I guess you just need to show that if you take two elements not in the same cyclic subgroup then the only subgroup containing both is the entire group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions on subgroups of $D_n$ are quite frequent on this site. It is certainly possible to give a short argument each time, but I think that the article of [Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf) is worth to be noted, because it gives all the necessary details to solve the questions in general. Section $3$ classifies all subgroups of $D_n$.